# How do I specify which Facebook birthdays show up in Calendar?

Tags: calendar, facebook

I do not want to disable all birthday events from showing up in Calendar from Facebook data, but I would like to specifically enable those that do.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No that is not possible. Only when you add Facebook friend manually to your contacts and add the birthdays... Then turn off the Facebook account in your contacts preferences.